# R radar chart axis labels cut off

Tags: r, radar-chart

I'm using a package called `radarchart` to plot a radar chart in R.

My dataframe is structured like this:

```
radar=data.frame(Dimension=c("Dim1","Dim2","Dim3","Dim4"),
Disney=c(0.7,0.9,0.7,0.4),
Sony=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8),Nokia=c(0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1))
```

And I use the `chartJSRadar` function to plot my radar chart.

```
chartJSRadar(scores = radar,showToolTipLabel = TRUE,labelSize = 
T,responsive = T,addDots = T,showLegend = F,width=650)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

**However I am unable to view the top and bottom axes in my app, as they are cut-off**

I suspect the solution has something to do with altering the `padding` however I am not able to find the right way to do it.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: `par(mar=c(10,5,10,5)` ?